# Spring ViewResolver : no mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I declared UrlBasedViewResolver method in `RestAppConfig` to render jsp page.

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver(){
    UrlBasedViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver(); //new UrlBasedViewResolver();//
    res.setOrder(10);
    res.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    res.setPrefix("/views/templates/");
    res.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return res;
}
```

and delclared ModelAndView method in controller `BaseController`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"kr.co.cdefi.base.restapp.controller"}
                , useDefaultFilters=false
                , includeFilters={@Filter(Controller.class)
                                ,  @Filter(ControllerAdvice.class)})
public class RestAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
            .useJaf(true)
            .favorPathExtension(true)
            .favorParameter(false)
            .ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    };

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver(); //new UrlBasedViewResolver();//
        res.setOrder(10);
        res.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        res.setPrefix("/views/templates/");
        res.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return res;
    }
}
```

finally, I run tomcat8 server using Eclipse. 
But requested URI `/home` just responses this.

> WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TheBigs/views/templates/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest-app'

I opened deployment location 
`...\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\TheBigs\views\templates\`

... files exists. What is the problem? Is there anything I missing?

- I added my controller code `BaseController`

  @Controller
  public class BaseController {
      Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class);

  ```
  @Autowired UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView home(){
      logger.debug("home!");
      ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
      view.setViewName("index");

      return view;
  }
  @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String index(Model model){
      logger.debug("index page!");
      model.addAttribute("message", "success");
      return "test";
  }
  ```

  }

There images are jsp files directory, and Web Deployment Assembly defined.
[image: JSP file directory]

[image]

Comment: This link explains with details how to use UrlBasedViewResolver: http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-urlbasedviewresolver-example-java-configuration                                        Be careful with the paths!

Comment: What is your request url get getting this error ? Did you add the the @RequestMapping for it?

Comment: @anvlasop Thank's for your comment. I read your link, but acutually don't know what am i missing. I located files on deploy path /views/css/templates, and prefix is same, too. Is threre something another care about setting ViewResolver bean ?

Comment: @Dinusha I missed upload my controller code. Of course, logback outputs in controller. so I thought that problem is related on **ViewResolver**. I'll modify my post now.

Comment: can you post your web.xml?

Comment: @Deh Yeah, It was uri-pattern problem. value **/*** changed to **/** then works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It caused by `servlet-mapping`.

I changed `url-pattern` set to `/` from `/*`, then works.